# Ignore C++ keywords in ANSI-C project header files - Netbeans IDE

Tags: c, netbeans, keyword

I have created a C-Application project and I want to use names such as `new` or `delete` in my project but I cannot due to their being reserved keywords in C++. How can I instruct Netbeans IDE to ignore C++ specific keywords ?

EDIT: Using `_new` or `_delete` would be a sloppy workaround and it is not what I am looking for.

EDIT2: This problem occurs only in `*.h` header files. When I type `new` or `delete` inside a `*.c`, file it does not get highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to avoid reusing keywords, even if they are not keywords in the dialect/version that you are **currently** using - you may wish, *or have*, to update the tool chain later.

Just use `New` and `Delete` instead or `mynew` & `mydelete`.

Answer (score 1):

A keyword in C++ that is not a keyword in C can be used as an identifier in C.

In my VC2008 IDE the editor still colors it as a reserved word, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a C-Application project and I want to use names such as
>   new or delete in my project but I cannot due to their being reserved
>   keywords in C++. How can I instruct Netbeans IDE to ignore C++
>   specific keywords ?

If you have created a ***C project***, this isn't an issue. It seems you have a C++ project instead. What file ending are you using? .c should work without problems -- even syntax coloring will not highlight new / delete for C files.

Just for testing you can create a simple project, with just a main`.c` and test a code with eg. `int new` variable.

> but I cannot due to their being reserved keywords in C++

Can you give us some more details on this?

Comment: See my EDIT2. It seems that this keyword highlight occurs only in `*.h` files.

Comment: This is because *.h files are used for C and C++. While there's a differentiation between C and C++ *source files*, there's no such for headers. I guess the only option to workaround this is to remove the file association *.h <--> C++; but that's *really* not a good solution.

Comment: Btw. you can check the language / file mapping here: **`Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Other`**. Unfortunately, changing default standard for *.h files to C doesn't solve this.